# Pocketsphinx error reading hub4.5000.DMP

Tags: pocketsphinx

I have configured pocketsphinx to work in ubuntu 14.04 and works in pocketsphinx_continous -inmic yes. I am working on a python program that records a .wav file using pyaudio and reads the wav file to decode the recording to text. I have used the latest version of pocketsphinx and has already installed all dependencies.

My python code:http://pastebin.com/kqLs34dC
I have posted my error: http://pastebin.com/NEG0RjGj

Thanks

Comment: It is fine to add a link to your whole code but could you include the relevant parts of the code and the output here?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen well whole  code is relevant as far as I am concerned. The problem i am encountering is that the speech doesnt get converted to text after recording the speech in a wav file. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this. Most of the codes available in the internet are out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to my own question. "print hypothesis.hypstr" prints the detected keyword to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

The model hub4.5000.DMP is corrupted, it was broken originally. You need to use latest model from cmusphinx repository, they will work fine.

Comment: I changed my program to point to the latest models  available from pocketsphinx repo.I've changed my pastes to the newer ones,but I still cant figure out why the speech doesnt get transcribed to text. Instead all I can see in the stdout is <pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Hypothesis *' at 0x7f148710ffc0> >